# Where is sp_describe_undeclared_parameters?

Tags: sql-server

I have an installation of SQL Server Enterprise edition 64 bit, V. 10.0.1600.22.

When I try to run [sp_describe_undeclared_parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-undeclared-parameters-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), I get "Could not find stored procedure". What is going on? This stored procedure should be in every edition of SQL Server since 2012, no ?

Comment: Run `SELECT @@VERSION` to get your edition.

Comment: You are using the RTM version of sql server 2008. 2008 is obsolete - but at a minimum you should have the last SP installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 10 is SQL Server 2008. So you are not on 2012, where this procedure was introduced.